# RESTful API urls best practice GET vs POST

Tags: android, rest, http, url

I am trying to create shopping app for android for that I am building REST API on my store site.
I wanna optimize and bring user better experience.
So my problem is that images of products, categories and other parts of store are resized according to web browser, so have relatively large size to mobile device.
So I decided to optimize this passing current width and height in request.

So I wonder what is the best practice and look of url to do this.

Now I have following url

```
mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53
```

So first time app is installed image settings is saved somewhere on the device and than used to request product using web site API.

I have thought about something like this

```
   mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53?width=100&height=100
```

But it seems weird what width and height does mean in this case ?

Also I thought about passing parameters in POST request, but POST request is used for storing something on the server.

So please suggest how url should look like in my case , what is the best practice or doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url should show what you want. Right now, you are requesting product; therefore, width and height are not meaningful.

```
mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53?width=100&height=100
```

I want product image in below url; therefore, width and height are more meaningful.

```
mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53/image?width=100&height=100
```

I normally want my services to be lean; thus, I would design my services like below. All selects will use GET method and other services will use other HTTP methods.

1. Most used product information

   mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53
2. Product Image is in a different method; since, image size will be large compared to product information, and some clients may not need it.

   mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53/image?width=100&height=100
3. Other details or extra information

   mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53/details
4. Of course, a service my incorporate all information.

   mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53/all
5. As you said in your question, POST/PUT/DELETE methods will be reserved for updating product information.

With this design, my clients will have a choice. Most of the time, normal product service and product image service will be used. Least used information will not travel in the network.

Comment: The second url looks better than first, is it good practice to do so ? For me it looks pretty good ,but I don't know about common used principles  
But it looks like that using this url I am trying to access only image not all info about product, is it good approach to do so , or it would be better to return resized url in general product response

Comment: @cbyoueyq Updated my answer to answer your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to limit the amount of information you want returned, the better way to do this is to allow the client to specify which fields the server should return. For instance, what if the 100x100 is a retina display? For someone with good eyes, a lot more information could be displayed. It's really up to the client to make that decision, not the server.

Comment: I am asking about url look and client can specify desired dimesnion